# Hadoop: how to set HADOOP_YARN_HOME correctly

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to setup hadoop with yarn.

The default yarn.application.classpath property is set like this.
yarn.application.classpath

```
<value>
   $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
   $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
   $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
   $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
   $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*,
</value>
```

With this configuration all MR jobs are failing. If I substitute it with this (HADOOP_YARN_HOME is substituted for its value) everything works fine.

```
<name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
<value>
   $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
   $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
   $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
   $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
   /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*,/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*,
</value>
```

So, I suspect that resourcemanager has an incorrect value of $HADOOP_YARN_HOME set somewhere. I've tried setting it in yarn-env.sh, hadoop-env.sh and /etc/default/hadoop-yarn, but jobs keep failing.

My question is, where do I have to set $HADOOP_YARN_HOME variable?

P.D. I'm using CDH5.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the configuration variables in **.bashrc** files belonging to that specific user.
Hope that help.